# Adding Opt-Out feature in Android app for Airpush Ads?

Tags: android, ads

Before anyone rants about Airpush, I would like to know a way to add an Opt-Out feature from within my app for Airpush Ads.

Is anyone familiar with the Airpush SDK? Their documentation is incredibly poor. Any help is appreciated.

I have searched the actual SDK for a solution to this, but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an Airpush representative.
Force's response is correct as one option, however to keep users inside your application we recommend also checking out the Permissions API. The Permissions API lets you create custom opt-in (whitelist) and opt-out (blacklist) functionality and fully control the user experience.

Click on the Permissions API button from within the Airpush developer portal.
For your purposes I would recommend selecting the Blacklist Mode, since you want to do opt-out rather than opt-in.

See below some documentation on the relevant API method once you've enabled Blacklist Mode from within the portal:

```
Add Blacklist IMEI

Developer sends an ‘add blacklist IMEI’ request to add an IMEI to blacklist in Airpush database. Note: In blacklist mode, blacklisted IMEIs will NOT qualify to receive push notification ads from Airpush.
URL - http://api.airpush.com/api.php
Supported request methods - GET, POST
Requires Authentication - Yes, API AUTH KEY
Parameters -
    Model   "app"
    Action  "add_imei_black"
    APIKEY  Generated API Key
    AppId   App id of application give above
    IMEI    Md5 encrypted IMEI that needs to be added in blacklist
Response Details - Upon successful blacklisting of an IMEI, server responds back with int value 1 along with the HTTP status code 200 (Created). If parameters are invalid, server will return HTTP status code as 400 and in case of any other errors server will respond back with the specific error code.
Sample Code
http://api.airpush.com/api.php?model=app&action=add_imei_black&APIKEY=apikey&appId=appid&imei=UserEncryptedIMEI
```

Comment: AirPush is a scam!! you never pay!! (to me and couple of buddies) or pay much less (found on google!!) ....You are THIEVES

Answer (score 1):

Even though I cannot recommend using Airpush, you can add a link in your application to this app: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.airpush.optoutapp

It is the official app from Airpush to opt-out. I don't think there is a way of manually disabling air push within the app.

Another way would be to redirect the user to this form
http://www.airpush.com/optout , however I would not recommend it, as the user has to enter his IMEI himself.

Please also note, that Airpush *will be still active* (=sends IMEI to server), but just won't show up.

Comment: I am currently trying <code>Airpush.disableSdk(this);</code>

Comment: Also, I am getting the feeling that everyone just hates Airpush. It is making devs some good money, but users don't like it. This is why I want to make an Opt-Out feature.

Comment: Yeah, you should definitely do that, otherwise you will get a lot of bad reviews. I guess the reason why users don't like it is that they don't know which app is causing these apps and because the ads are also showing up when the app is not active.